# Insert Content Before and After an Element Without Autoclosing tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert, tags

Say I have the following:

```
<div id="content">content</div>
```

And I want to insert some stuff before it ** (notice the unclosed div)**:

```
$("#content").before("<div>pre-pre-content</div><div>pre-content ");
```

And some then some more after ** (notice I am now closing the div)**:

```
$("#content").after(" post-content</div><div>post-post-content</div>");
```

My desired output is:

```
<div>pre-pre content</div>
<div>
    pre-content <div id="content">content</div> post-content
</div>
<div>post-post content</div>
```

Instead, what I get is:

```
<div>pre-pre content</div>
<div>pre-content</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
<div>post-content</div>
<div>post-post content</div>
```

Because jQuery is automatically "correcting" the unclosed tags.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz373/1/)**

Is there a way to use .wrap() to add different content before and after an element without automatically closing tags?

Note, I **cannot** do the following because of an unrelated restriction:

```
$("#content").html("<div>Content before " + $("#content).html() + " Content after</div>")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't insert partial or unclosed tags.  Inserting elements in the DOM must insert only whole elements.

Your choices are:

1. Extract the element you want to be wrapped in your new element, insert the new container object and then put your original element into the container.
2. Manipulate the HTML of a parent directly (generally not recommended).
3. Use the jQuery `.wrap()` method which does the option in #1 for you.  See [here](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) for more info on jQuery's `.wrap()`.

Comment: ok that makes sense, didn't know that about jQuery. The more specific issue I'm running into is that my content is an embedded tweet and when I try to extract it and reinsert it, it goes blank: http://jsfiddle.net/zSks5/

Comment: I think I should actually open another question with these specifics, but if you have any idea on a fix let me know

Comment: for the record, tweet specific question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14844573/1179207