# jQuery: Copying an Embedded Tweet's HTML

Tags: jquery, twitter, embed, tweets

Say I have an embedded tweet inside a div:

```
<div id="tweet">
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p>A lion would never cheat on his wife. But a Tiger Wood.</p>&mdash; Puns (@omgthatspunny) <a href="https://twitter.com/omgthatspunny/status/301482080490115072">February 13, 2013</a></blockquote>
    <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>

<div id="tweet-insert"></div>
```

And I want to copy the tweet and insert it into another div:

```
var tweetHtml = $("#tweet").html();
$("#tweet-insert").html(tweetHtml);
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ww6e/2/)**.

This doesn't work and it makes me **:(**

Any idea on a fix?

Comment: If I switch your fiddle to jQuery 1.9 and run, it works for me.

Comment: fiddle link revised to be on jQuery 1.9, still doesn't work for me (shows up blank). I'm using the latest version of Chrome. You see two identical embedded tweets?

Comment: I guess a better example would be -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ww6e/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.clone()` like this:

```
var tweetCopy = $("#tweet").clone();
$("#tweet-insert").append(tweetCopy);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9Segq/

Comment: thanks this does seem to work, however what about trying to insert the copied tweet into a div? http://jsfiddle.net/9Segq/5/

Comment: Why do you insist on using the HTML rather than the cloning the actual objects?  Some HTML cannot be straight copied (conflicting IDs, event handlers, etc...).

Comment: @DougieBear - If you want content before/after the insertion, you can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sqX4D/

Comment: haha don't want to insist on anything, just trying to put the tweet in a div that I am creating with javascript, then add that div to the page: http://jsfiddle.net/9Segq/9/

Comment: @DougieBear - I provided a better way of doing that in my previous comment.

Comment: Cool I like that way but the copied tweets are showing up as blank boxes for me, are they not for you? I'm in latest version of Chrome

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24408/discussion-between-dougie-bear-and-jfriend00)

Answer (score 1):

the script loads asynchronous, so it may happen that it's not loaded yet when you try to  copy the contents.

Copy the contents when the `load`-event of the script fires: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/MSfvT/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/MSfvT/)

Comment: i want to copy the embedded tweet exactly as it appears, not just the text. however this is interesting and taught me something so you get my upvote :)

Comment: It should appear as desired, When not it may be a caching-issue, try to add a changing parameter to the script-src(e.g. a timestamp)